# How could prevent grow width of flex div by it's content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'v been created a nested div with flex and i want that follow flex rules in grow and shrink, but when inner text or content get long then div grow as too long. in this fiddle i marked it with **"This is a bug"** and as you can see the text in this div is longer than other and parent flex div grew as i don't want. I set `flex: 1 1 auto;` and i don't know where is need to change. Any advise appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/JZHag/

Comment: You mean something like that http://jsfiddle.net/JZHag/7/ ?

Comment: @Alek i tried to max-width be in percent but i think you right and i must set exact length for it. I add overflow: hidden; and some narration to be useful and i'll update that asap. Just could you please why you used word-wrap:break-word; because i don't want to show overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i posted in my comment [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZHag/7/) i used static max-width because i believe is good solution for your case.

**css**

```
html, body {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}

.WholeDiv{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.mainContainer{

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 512px;

    height: 232px;
    line-height: 232px;

    z-index: 999;

    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainContainer .firstContent {
    flex: 1 1 auto; 
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 140px;
    text-align: right; 
}

.mainContainer .secondContent {
    width: 232px;
    min-width: 232px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.mainContainer .thirdContent {
    flex: 1 1 auto; 
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
}

.mainContainerVert{

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;


    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;


    -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
    -moz-box-pack: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column no-wrap;
    flex-flow: column no-wrap;    



    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;

    background-color: blue;
    /*min-width: 100px;*/
    height: 232px;
    line-height: 232px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.mainContainerVert .dvRow{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    max-height: 32px;
    width: 98%;
    max-width: 300px;
    /*min-width: 100px;*/
    text-align: center;   
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: flex;
}

SPAN{
    /*flex: 1 1 auto;*/
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    /*min-width: 100px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    /*white-space: no-wrap;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZHag/15/)

Also remove from `span` `flex: 1 1 auto;`. I think that is no need.

Comment: exactly i need to .dvRow or inner span wide itself to fill space but don't change .firstContent and .thirdContent as to be shown not equal by inside text. static value can't be done. It's good if we can't solve it but that's my real solution. if you can do that i appreciate and will mark this as answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Didn't get what exactly you mean with this "dvRow or inner span wide itself to fill space but don't change". What space? And ".thirdContent as to be shown not equal by inside text" :)

Comment: you right, maybe i couldn't describe well. Suppose we changing browser width so normal behavior is growing .firstContent and .thirdContent and there must be equal because of flex: 1 1 auto; Now i need these grow or shrink just when we change browser size and not when inner text is to long or to short. in the first fiddle i attached you can see the text "this is bug" affected .firstContent width and that growth was not equal with .thirdContent . notice in your last fiddle when change window size to get large, .firstContent growing more than .thirdContent again.  Can i explain well? :)

Comment: i changed source you can see in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/JZHag/11/  and solve this by adding display: flex; to .dvRow and set flex: 1 1 auto; for Span. Actually i used flex in down level again and it seems can help. Please read and tell me what you think.

Comment: Yeah that is what i have in mind(after your first comment) but wasn't sure. I think that will work :)

Comment: Thanks dud :) so as i don't want to write new response and set my own text as answer, please update your answer with this approach if you don't mind and then i set that is answer to help somebody who need this.

Comment: Updated. See also my comment and tell if you agree :)

Comment: Yeah, flex: 1 1 auto; isn't need more for SPAN because of single content, but if we decide to contain more then one element inside SPAN it must accompanied with it. Anyway i think it good as enough. I'll set it as answer and hope anyone need this read whole article to understand things. Good luck man :)